# Basic Apache2 question regarding pointing to a new conf for /var/www/mySite.com

Tags: apache2

I've setup my virtual host with a conf file and enabled it, yet I would like to change the default "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" to my own html.

the default points to `/var/www/html/index.html`
I would like my AWS EC2 to point to the new conf I created.
How do I do that?

And also have a php file as default instead of html, would that require an .htaccess file?

Thanks,Bud.

Answer (score 0):

You can either edit the /var/www/html/index.html file or edit your conf to point to the dir of your pages.
You don't need an .htaccess file.
Make sure you restart apache:

```
## Start command ##
systemctl start apache2.service

## Stop command ##
systemctl stop apache2.service

## Restart command ##
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor to point to your new conf:

$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_server_domain_or_IP.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .
    DocumentRoot /var/www/your_new_dir
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close. Now check your configuration:

$ sudo apache2ctl configtest

Output should be "syntax OK". Then reload apache2:

$ sudo systemctl reload apache2